# Getting the first index of dropdown value to all events on calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coming to a problem where I select from my dropdown and then I want to select another option from dropdown, I get the same value on my previous selection of option and my new selected option. Is there a fix to my code below? please advise. thank you very much for your help.

Here is my code:

```js
 

$('.outputId').html(
        $("#eventname option:selected").text()
        
        );
   
    $('#eventname').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" for="eventname" name="eventname" id="eventname" data-val="true">
<option value="3e0ffa1d-c715-433c-b209-b6083bb43bf6" class="details" type="text">LeBron James</option>
<option value="3f66debb-a4f7-4c91-8bfc-a3fa62755f7d" class="details" type="text">Tester</option>
<option value="66653381-1009-4573-8d0e-640c57e94e5d" class="details" type="text">Jason Jones</option>
<option value="880c26f4-cb23-45ba-928b-50e9cd293c65" class="details" type="text">Sam Smith</option>
 <div class="button">
       

 <input type="submit" id="but"/>
        </div>
<div id="event">
<header></header>
<ul>
 <li>
  <p class="outputId"></p>   
 </li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you exemplify what you mean with "I select from my dropdown and then I want to select another option from dropdown, I get the same value on my previous selection of option and my new selected option"?

Comment: So, I have a dropdown with options. Whenever I select the first option - I get the correct option. And then, I go to the dropdown and select on another option. Then in my div `outputId` I see my new selected options that I have selected. Basically, my previous selected option is gone and overwriten with the new option as in I have duplicates of new option selected name.

Comment: Please include your event handler logic in your question.  Keeping in mind it sounds like you are expecting `html()` to perform an append, rather than a replace, which it is designed to do.

Comment: check my handler logic shown in my code above. and correct. But you understand what I want to achieve, right?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your selection to be shown in the output div you need to hook to the change event of the select:

```
$('select#eventname').on('change',function(e){
    var l_strSelOpt = $(e.target).find('option[value="'+$(e.target).val() + '"]').html().trim();
    $('.outputId').html(l_strSelOpt);
});
```

The code above is executed when you change the selection. It pulls the html of the option which value corresponds to the value of the select. The last part(get text from the selected option) can be done in many ways, so feel free to experiment with it.

Comment: So your code is good. However, when I select an option, submit to div. and then when I try to get a new dropdown value it updates the the previous selection with the new dropdown selection

Comment: correct. But I dont want the previous added selected option to get changed with a new option selection

Comment: well append it then. It you want to wrap it in html you can do that also.

Comment: append just added the selection option on the div. How I want it is lets say I have a calendar where when I select on a date and a  pop up opens up with a dropdown, in that dropdown I select a name for that particular date, and then next day date I select a different option selection. You get now? :)

Comment: In this image: https://imgur.com/a/JC7Ao9K I get the previous event selected with first dropdown of option. However, on the next day event  I choose another dropdown option to show. Do you get now? Right now as the image shows it shows "Sams Smith" for both events. Which I selected the first event a different option

Comment: hey, I have updated my jquery code. So, that code I posted is fine but  I get the output as my first index of all my items , no matter what I select on the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `</select>` tag. Then you can use this script:

```
$('#eventname').on('change', ()=>{
    $('.outputId').html(
       $("#eventname option:selected").text()
   );
})
```

Comment: Yours is fine. However, when I select the first option and then I add it to my div, and then I want to add another option - it gives the same option that I created before.

Comment: I create playground example for you, maybe it will help: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/egb0axnu/6/

Comment: yes, can I do `$("#eventname option:selected").empty()` to clear out the selected option, after I select?

Comment: Yes, you can do this: `$("#eventname").val($("#eventname option:first").val())` https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/egb0axnu/9/

Comment: So, I copied your code and I when I select on another option it goes back to the first

Comment: oh I get what you mean, you can call .remove() method: `$("#eventname option:selected").remove()`, but if you want to see the original options again, then you need to first copy the values of the deleted item

Comment: `$("#eventname option:selected").remove()` removed from dropdown which I dont want that to happen. For example: How I want it is lets say I have a calendar where when I select on a date and a pop up opens up with a dropdown, in that dropdown I select a name for that particular date, and then next day date I select a different option selection without the previous date dropdown option getting affected

Comment: Okey, see my example, i think this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/egb0axnu/30/#&togetherjs=tpVw4kUlwn

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `change listener` and change in that.

**Note:** missing `</select>` tag

```js
$( "#eventname" ).change(function() {    
  $('.outputId').html($(this).find(":selected").text());
  $('.valueId').html($(this).val());
  $('.appendedVal').append(`<li>${$(this).find(":selected").text()}</li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" for="eventname" name="eventname" id="eventname" data-val="true">
<option value="3e0ffa1d-c715-433c-b209-b6083bb43bf6" class="details" type="text">LeBron James</option>
<option value="3f66debb-a4f7-4c91-8bfc-a3fa62755f7d" class="details" type="text">Tester</option>
<option value="66653381-1009-4573-8d0e-640c57e94e5d" class="details" type="text">Jason Jones</option>
<option value="880c26f4-cb23-45ba-928b-50e9cd293c65" class="details" type="text">Sam Smith</option>
</select>
<div id="event">

<p class="outputId">test</p>  
<p class="valueId">value</p> 
<ul class="appendedVal"></ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: So, I switched `.val()` to `.text()` and I am getting all of the dropdown options as selected

Comment: However, when I select the first option and then I add it to my div, and then I want to add another option - it gives the same option that I created before

Comment: I have updated my solution, I pointed out the missing piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

> Try with .append() instead of .text()

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#eventname").change(function () { 
 $(".outputId").append($("#eventname option:selected").text())
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" for="eventname" name="eventname" id="eventname" data-val="true">
<option value="3e0ffa1d-c715-433c-b209-b6083bb43bf6" class="details" type="text">LeBron James</option>
<option value="3f66debb-a4f7-4c91-8bfc-a3fa62755f7d" class="details" type="text">Tester</option>
<option value="66653381-1009-4573-8d0e-640c57e94e5d" class="details" type="text">Jason Jones</option>
<option value="880c26f4-cb23-45ba-928b-50e9cd293c65" class="details" type="text">Sam Smith</option>
</select>
<div id="event">
<header></header>
<ul>
 <li>
  <p class="outputId"></p>    `
 </li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

> Direct append **li** element to **ul** list items

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#eventname").change(function () { 
$(".outputId").append( '<li>' +$("#eventname option:selected").text() + '</li>')
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" for="eventname" name="eventname" id="eventname" data-val="true">
<option value="3e0ffa1d-c715-433c-b209-b6083bb43bf6" class="details" type="text">LeBron James</option>
<option value="3f66debb-a4f7-4c91-8bfc-a3fa62755f7d" class="details" type="text">Tester</option>
<option value="66653381-1009-4573-8d0e-640c57e94e5d" class="details" type="text">Jason Jones</option>
<option value="880c26f4-cb23-45ba-928b-50e9cd293c65" class="details" type="text">Sam Smith</option>
</select>
<div id="event">
<header></header>
<ul class="outputId"></ul>
</div>
```

> Restrict Duplicates with message popup

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#eventname").change(function () {
let isDuplicate=false;
$('.outputId li').each(function(){
isDuplicate=$(this).text()==$("#eventname option:selected").text();
if (isDuplicate)
{
return false;
}
}) 
if($('.outputId li').length==0 || !isDuplicate){
$(".outputId").append( '<li>' +$("#eventname option:selected").text() + '</li>')
}
else{
alert('Duplicate Selected')
}
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" for="eventname" name="eventname" id="eventname" data-val="true">
<option value="3e0ffa1d-c715-433c-b209-b6083bb43bf6" class="details" type="text">LeBron James</option>
<option value="3f66debb-a4f7-4c91-8bfc-a3fa62755f7d" class="details" type="text">Tester</option>
<option value="66653381-1009-4573-8d0e-640c57e94e5d" class="details" type="text">Jason Jones</option>
<option value="880c26f4-cb23-45ba-928b-50e9cd293c65" class="details" type="text">Sam Smith</option>
</select>
<div id="event">
<header></header>
<ul class="outputId"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this when first I add a option and it adds to my div, and then I want to add another option from dropdown, It gives the first index and something like this: https://imgur.com/a/wFin5Wx

Comment: can I clear out the selected option when I select on a option?

Comment: So, with `Direct append li element to ul list items` code I still get latest selected option

Comment: this will be fine for clearing after selection, right? ` $('#eventname').empty();`?

Comment: and yes I am trying your card

Comment: so  $('.outputId').empty();

Comment: yes, you can use div or element Id where you want to clear it out

Comment: you do not want duplicates added in your list, am I correct?

Comment: yes. Like for  I  have a calendar and I want to add different users on each date on calendar

Comment: Basically, I have a calendar and I add in events by click on the calendar day, on the popup UI it opens my dropdown where I select in users as. And then I choose another day and select a different option it will show the new option and my previous date is also selected with new option value

Comment: So, this `$(".outputId").append($("#eventname option:selected").text())` works but it still overwrites my previous selected option

Comment: please check for last one, it is restricting duplicate items to get added

Comment: So, this $(".outputId").append($("#eventname option:selected").text()) works but it still overwrites my previous selected option

Comment: check my html I have added .outputId class to ul and removed everything in there.

Comment: I dont want a list though `<li>`, so I just left it as `<p>`